# Why `echo -n` doesn't work in this script on mac terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, command-line

I am learning shell from tutorialspoint today:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-shell-loops.htm

And I copied this code block to a `loop.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/sh

a=0
while [ "$a" -lt 10 ]    # this is loop1
do
   b="$a"
   while [ "$b" -ge 0 ]  # this is loop2
   do
      echo -n "$b "
      b=`expr $b - 1`
   done
   echo
   a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```

But when excute it, I got things like:

```
...
-n 4
-n 3
-n 2
-n 1
-n 0
...
```

Apparently, the `-n` flag doesn't work in `echo -n "$b "`.

Then I move the same file to my Ubuntu virtual system. Runs it.

I got ：

```
0
1 0
2 1 0
3 2 1 0
4 3 2 1 0
5 4 3 2 1 0
6 5 4 3 2 1 0
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

I'm confused, though Ubuntu use dash as its default `sh`, but OSX use official `bourne shell` as its `sh`, why the script failed here? How to fix it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Echo is both a binary program (`/bin/echo`) as well as builtin command in some shells such as bash and sh.  As `man echo` states,

> ```
>  Some shells may provide a builtin echo command which is similar or iden-
>  tical to this utility.  Most notably, the builtin echo in sh(1) does not
>  accept the -n option.  Consult the builtin(1) manual page.
> ```

In order to fix this, you can change your script to use bash by setting the first line to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Or change your invocation of echo to

```
/bin/echo -n "$b "
```

Comment: So tutorialspoint made a mistake?

Comment: Possibly but sh is not the same everywhere e.g. on OS X it is link to bash on other Unicies can be ash etc. (or even sh) and the POSIX [definition of echo](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) says -n is not portable

Comment: @Zen, Tutorials.com probably assumed Linux.  Mark, you are absolutely right. Since this is on Ask Different I answered for OS X.

Comment: 1, OSX (Atleast 10.10.x) Bash does not use builtin echo. 2. `If bash is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical  versions of sh as closely as possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well.` The Builtin echo for Bash as SH will work as SH's builtin echo should. It will act differently than the Bash builtin echo.

Comment: @cde, are you sure that bash does not use the built-in echo? Invoked as /bin/bash or as /bin/sh, `type echo` returns `echo is a shell builtin` for me.

Comment: Geez, your right. Just tried `/bin/echo -e "\n"` and it doesn't parse the newline character. Because the OS X echo lacks "-e" support, but the builtin bash one does. Damn it apple.

Answer (score 16):

`echo` is not portable as you experienced. I would suggest to use the POSIX alternative `printf`:

```
printf "$b "
```

Note that in the general case, if you don't know in advance what contains `$b`, you should use instead:

```
printf "%s " "$b"
```

Comment: Just quick note that if anything in `$b` starts with a dash you should do `printf -- "$b "` otherwise it will throw an error.

Comment: @Ulukai That's correct but not robust enough as it would still choke if `$b` contains `%`. My suggestion was limited to the OP case.

Answer (score 2):

Appending '\c' as per "man echo" documentation seemed to do this for me. So ... on line 9 the change would like below

```
#!/bin/sh

a=0
while [ "$a" -lt 10 ]    # this is loop1
do
   b="$a"
   while [ "$b" -ge 0 ]  # this is loop2
   do
      echo "$b \c"
      b=`expr $b - 1`
   done
   echo
   a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```

Comment: This'll work for some versions of `echo` (under some conditions), but in other cases it might just print "`\c`" as part of the output (unless you also supply the `-e` option, but then some versions will print *that*...). Overall, if you value your sanity, use `printf` instead of `echo` for any situation where you need to skip the newline and/or process escape sequences.

Answer (score 2):

The builtin echo for `/bin/sh` on macOS does not support the `-n` option. You can use the following alternatives:

### bash

Using `/bin/bash` works. But I don't like using it for scripts because it is not available by default for example on FreeBSD. On Linux it is available.

### builtin echo and tr

If you want to use the builtin `echo` (e.g. when you are echoing a password and do not want to appear in `ps`) and want to have it more portable, you can use:

```
echo hello | tr -d '\n'
```

### printf or /bin/echo

Otherwise `printf` or `/bin/echo -n` are good options, too.

Just be aware that `printf` takes a formatted string, so if you are including a variable in the string that might include a `%` or `\` character, it might break things. For example:

```
$ w=%world ; printf "hello $w"
printf: %w: invalid directive
hello %
```

In such case you can use %s as format string.

```
$ w=%world ; printf %s "hello $w"
hello %world
```

### `\c` suffix

Another option is appending `\c` to the end of the string when using `echo` (see `man echo` on macOS). It works fine on macOS but it's not very portable.